# Difference between two syntaxes of join (pyspark)

Tags: python, dataframe, join, pyspark

I have a question about the difference two syntaxes of join in PySpark,

For example, I have these two dataframes

**DF1**

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | OLIVER |
| 2 | MICHAEL |
| 3 | JUSTIN |

**DF2**

| ID | address |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | BRAZIL |
| 1 | FRANCE |
| 2 | PORTUGAL |
| 2 | ARGENTINA |
| 3 | MEXICO |

Usually I use:

`df1.join(df2, (col('df1.ID') == col('df2.ID')), 'left')`

But sometimes I see people using:

`df1.join(df2, 'ID', 'left')`

So, my question is, what is the difference between this two codes?

I'm trying to understand the difference between the first and second syntax of join.

Comment: They both do the same. You're just typing more out. Guess it's personal preference.

Comment: The first method is used when the column names on which they need to joined are different in left and right dataframe. The second method is used when you are sure that column name to join on is same in both dataframes.

Comment: The first one is flexible and generalised; it can join on any boolean expression. The second one is short-hand for the first one, but only for the simple case you presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the following mean the same thing:

| Join | Desc | Type of second arg `on` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `df1.join(df2, 'ID')` | a string for the join column name | `str` |
| `df1.join(df2, ['ID'])` | a list of column names | `List[str]` |
| `df1.join(df2, col('df1.ID') == col('df2.ID'))` | a join expression (Column) | `pyspark.sql.column.Column` |
| `df1.join(df2, df1.ID == df2.ID)` | a join expression (Column) | `pyspark.sql.column.Column` |

If you had a composite key of two columns (`ck1, ck2`) instead of single `ID`. All of the following mean the same thing:

| Join | Desc | Type of second arg `on` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `df1.join(df2, ['ck1', 'ck1'])` | a list of column names | `List[str]` |
| `df1.join(df2, [col('df1.pk1') == col('df2.pk1'), col('df1.pk2') == col('df2.pk2')])` | list of join expressions | `List[pyspark.sql.column.Column]` |
| `df1.join(df2, [df1.ck1 == df2.ck1, df1.ck2 == df2.ck2])` | list of join expressions | `List[pyspark.sql.column.Column]` |

*Ignoring the `how='left'` as it's same*

---

As [documentation of `DataFrame.join()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html) says:

```py
DataFrame.join(other: pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame, 
               on: Union[
                       str,
                       List[str],
                       pyspark.sql.column.Column,
                       List[pyspark.sql.column.Column],
                       None
                    ] = None,
               how: Optional[str] = None
            ) → pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame[source]
```

> `on`: `str`, `list` or `Column`, optional
>
> - a string for the join column name,
> - a list of column names,
> - a join expression (Column), or
> - a list of Columns.
>
> If on is a string or a list of strings indicating the name of the join column(s), the column(s) must exist on both sides, and >this performs an equi-join.

Answer (score 0):

If you are joining on a column that has the same name in both dataframes, it is cleaner to use the second option.
The first option can be used if you are joining on columns with different names. For example if in df1 the ID column was named USER_ID, and you don't wish to rename the column, you should join as:

```
df1.join(df2, (col('df1.USER_ID') == col('df2.ID')), 'left')
```

or

```
df1.join(df2, df1.USER_ID == df2.ID, 'left')
```